# Parachain Not Compiling

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, polkadot-sdk

We are updating parachain template in `v1.6.0`,when building by using `cargo build --release`, we're getting weird error.
Can someone suggest what we are doing wrong?

[Github repo](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/Xcavate_chain)

[ErrorFile Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Z6MFNBhY-fBxf1sjML2KjcC8ssFjOmI/view?usp=drive_link)

```
match_types! {
         | ^^^^^^^^^^^
         |
         = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `smallvec`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:143:9
          |
      143 |         smallvec![WeightToFeeCoefficient {
          |         ^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `impl_opaque_keys`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:174:1
          |
      174 | impl_opaque_keys! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `create_runtime_str`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:182:16
          |
      182 |     spec_name: create_runtime_str!("template-parachain"),
          |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `create_runtime_str`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:183:16
          |
      183 |     impl_name: create_runtime_str!("template-parachain"),
          |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:249:1
          |
      249 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the attribute macro `derive_impl`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:282:3
          |
      282 | #[derive_impl(frame_system::config_preludes::ParaChainDefaultConfig as frame_system::DefaultConfig)]
          |   ^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:324:1
          |
      324 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:347:1
          |
      347 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:367:1
          |
      367 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:394:1
          |
      394 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:435:1
          |
      435 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `parameter_types`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:463:1
          |
      463 | parameter_types! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `construct_runtime`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:498:1
          |
      498 | construct_runtime!(
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `impl_runtime_apis`
         --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:546:1
          |
      546 | impl_runtime_apis! {
          | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |
          = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
    
      error[E0412]: cannot find type `RelayNetwork` in this scope
        --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/parachain-template/runtime/src/xcm_config.rs:43:21
         |
      
          |
                
    ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air parachain-template %
```